# sprintf (PHP) return unwanted character (×)

Tags: php, printf

I tried the sprintf function in php, but the results were not as expected, add an undesirable character:

```
https://localhost/item?item_id=abcd&redirect=https://www.google.com/×tamp=1616847526
```

unwanted is `×`

the results I expected:

```
https://localhost/item?item_id=abcd&redirect=https://www.google.com/&timestamp=1616847657
```

This is my code.

```
public function generateUrl()
{
    $url = sprintf(
        '%s%s?item_id=%s&redirect=%s&timestamp=%s',
        'https://localhost',
        '/item',
        'abcd',
        'https://www.google.com/',
        $this->timestamp,
    );
    return $url;
}
```

If I replace the `timestamp` string with something else the result will be fine. What's wrong with `timestamp`? how to solve it?

thanks.

Comment: Look at [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode). `&` should be `&amp;`. `&times;` brings that `x`.

Comment: That's the `&times` sign, as in "`&times`tamp" (which should be `&times;` but some browsers might be lax in interpreting it)

Comment: There is nothing in the question that will generate the string `×tamp=...` - the string `timestamp` is not a variable - please update the question to accurately represent the problem you are seeing in a reproducible manner

Comment: Please share your debugging approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with `sprintf`, `&times` is the HTML entity for the multiplication sign `x`.

If you really need to display the generated URL as you're doing now you can either use `return htmlentities($url)` instead of returning the `$url` directly, or by changing the `sprintf` call to :

```
$url = sprintf(
        '%s%s?item_id=%s&amp;redirect=%s&amp;timestamp=%s',
        'https://localhost',
        '/item',
        'abcd',
        'https://www.google.com/',
        $this->timestamp,
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

To display an URL in HTML, you should use [`htmlspecialchars($url)`](https://php/.net/htmlspecialchars) to convert `&` to `&amp;`.

```
https://localhost/item?item_id=abcd&amp;redirect=https://www.google.com/&amp;timestamp=1616847657
```

Also, you could use [`http_build_query()`](https://php.net/http_build_query) to generate a **valid URL**.

```
public function generateUrl()
{
    $data = [
        'item_id'   => 'abcd',
        'redirect'  => 'https://www.google.com/',
        'timestamp' => $this->timestamp,
    ];
    return 'https://localhost/item?' . http_build_query($data);
}
```

Output:

```
https://localhost/item?item_id=abcd&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&timestamp=1616849241
```